How to generate Power BI chart in an external application?
I'm creating an application (outside of Power BI) and would like to embed a Power BI chart into it. I already have the .pbix file with the chart created.
The idea is the user clicks a "Generate Report" button in the application.
Then the application submits the user data to Power BI and Power BI returns the generated chart for the user (inside the application).
The user would never open Power BI.
How to implement this external refresh/retrieval from Power BI?
